# JSON array into a tableView cell

Tags: json, ios4, uitableview, nsarray

After an HTTP request I receive a JSON array decoded with:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [stringResponse JSONValue];
```

The array looks like:

```
(
{
    id = 0000000002;
    ora = "15:00:00";
    oraArrivo = "21:20:00";
},
    {
    id = 0000000001;
    ora = "19:20:00";
    oraArrivo = "23:30:00";
}
)
```

Now I have to insert every array item in one uitableview row. I tried with:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

but it's not working. I probably need something more.

Another part of the "original" UiTableView's code I edited is:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return jsonArray.count;
}
```

I just need to have rows in the tableView like

> "Departure time is 15:00:00 arrival time is 21:20:00"

Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.jsonArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"ora"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"oraArrvo"];
```